# Photo viewer on canvas

Tags: html, canvas

Is it possible to create a photo viewer using `canvas`? User uploads photos and then can watch them.

Maybe any advice, solution or articles?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes easily possible, but? Why upload to see photos they already have on there local storage. Maybe you want to create a photo viewer, without uploading?  If you wish to create a cloud storage solution for users you should not be doing it yourself if you have to ask this type of question. Hosting a cloud storage solution is expensive and the market is saturated .I think you should be more specific in your question, it's too ambiguous for anyone to answer as it is.

Comment: @Blindman67, thanks, but I really want users to upload their photos. But it isn't a question. Question is to watch images via canvas. How to do it?

Comment: Easy. To load an image `img= new Image(); img.src="imageURL"` once loaded to render it the canvas is just as simple `canvas2DContext.drawImage(img, xPos, yPos)` very simple and also just as easy to pan, zoom, rotate, add filters, fade them in and out. Also works with videos, Canvas is a very simple API to use, and is powered by the device GPU so its all silky smooth at 60 frames a second.